# DataGridView add buttons and text to Header Row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` that I populate from a loop.
If I do the following:

```
public Form(Dictionary<String, String> headers)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (var key in headers.Keys) {
        datagridview1.Columns.Add(key, key);
    }
}
```

I get a header row containing text.

How do I add buttons and text to the header row of datagridview1 instead of just text?

I am using `winforms` and `.net 4.5`. (I guess I could switch to 4.5.1 if it makes things easier).

Comment: Did it/you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible.  Here are ways you could get close:

- Set the first row's [`Frozen` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.frozen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and put the buttons in the first row.
- Add a right-click menu to expose the functions you want to add.

Answer (score -1):

May thats helping you

```
 DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);
 btn.HeaderText = "YourText";
 btn.Text = "YourText";
 btn.Name = "DGVbutton1";
 btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```

Comment: When downvoting, please tell me why you downvoted my answer!